# Even and Odd Post Separation in Blogger

Tags: html, blogs, blogger

I have a blog in Blogger platform. Now i want to assign two different classes alternatively for blog posts. How it will be possible?
Let me clarify this things properly. Say my blog contains 5 posts - post1, post2, post3, post4 and post5. After assigning two different classes alternatively it will be ...

```
<div class="posts odd_post">post1</div>
<div class="posts even_post">post2</div>
<div class="posts odd_post">post3</div>
<div class="posts even_post">post4</div>
<div class="posts odd_post">post5</div>
```

something like that..
Now is it possible with the help of `<b:if cond='....` tags ??
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the Best of my knowledge,this is not possible

However,here is a trick

Tag all odd posts as "odd" using lables 
Tag all even posts as "even" using lables

Then use Label conditional tags

Here is a [link](http://www.thesimplexdesign.com/2013/08/simplex-colorblock-template-for.html) to template which uses this for different colors among different posts.

Answer (score 1):

you can use css3 property,

```
.post:nth-child(odd) // for odd-post
{

}

.post:nth-child(even)
{

}
```